# Spatialite WITH clause issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, spatialite, spatialite-gui

I've encountered an issue: when I try to execute in *Spatialite_GUI* query that contains `WITH` clause I get `SQL error: near "with": syntax error`. Also `WITH` unlike `SELECT` and other keywords is not highlighted inside SQL-querry window. The same query in *SQLite Manager* works just fine. Found no treads on this issue. Is this my local problem?

*Spatialite_GUI 1.7.1-1.5*, *SQLite Manager 0.8.1*, *OpenSUSE 13.1*.

**EDIT:**

Actually the issue is deeper. DB Manager in QGIS 2.4 also throws the same error for the `WITH` clause (`WHITH` in sql window is highlighted in this case).

> General info
>
> SQLite version: 
>   3.7.17
>
> SpatiaLite
>
> Library: 
>   4.1.1  GEOS: 
>   3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921  Proj:  Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012

Comment: The example query from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html `WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<1000000) SELECT x FROM cnt;` works for me with spatialite-gui 1.8.0-dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running against SQLite version 3.7.17, but Common Table Expressions (WITH clause) were not supported until 3.8.3.  See change log here: http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Unless you are trying to do a recursive query, you can either write your WITH clause as a view or use a subquery.

Comment: Ok, but why I'm able to use `WITH` clause from within _SQLite Manager_ for the same database?

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I am unable to check the bindings at the moment. Can you append that to your answer?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to do? I don't think that I understood you.

Comment: The same general info that you posted for DM Manager regarding the SQLite version, etc.  Wait, are you referring to the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox? If so, it likely is compiled with a recent version of SQLite.  To clarify, whether or not you can use a Common Table Expression depends on the client that you are using, not the version of the database file.

Comment: Yes it is the plugin for Firefox (version 0.8.1, added to question). Seems that my only option is to update SQLite to 3.8. The main need for WITH was a recursive query...

Comment: SQLite is actually divided into two parts: the data file and the database program itself. The data file is the .sqlite file that you deliver to users. However, the program part must be installed on each computer that is using SQLite database files. For example on Windows the program may be sqlite3.dll or then it is compiled into some .exe file (for example spatialite-gui.exe). There can be loads of different sqlite3 versions on a Windows computer. To check which version is really in use run SQL query `SELECT sqlite_version();`